# What is the fastest way to find an array within another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, search

Is there any equivalent of String.indexOf() for arrays? If not, is there any faster way to find an array within another other than a linear search?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? Maybe with a code sample.

Comment: No, there isn't. And how could you improve on a linear search for unsorted arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the elements of your arrays, I believe this is not much different than the string search problem.

This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) provides a general intro to the various known algorithms.

[Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-karp) and [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) might be your best options.

You should be able to find Java implementations of these algorithms and adapt them to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(myArray);
Collections.sort(list);
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, find);
```

OR

```
public static int indexOf(Object[][] array, Object[] find){
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++){
    if (Arrays.equals(array[i], find)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

OR

```
public static int indexOf(Object[] array, Object find){
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++){
    if (array[i].equals(find)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

OR

```
Object[] array = ...
int index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(find);
```

Comment: I placed many methods because you question was not 100% clear. I think the first option is best if you have a really large set. But i suggest you try them all out for speed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is NO way to find an array within another without a linear search.  String.indexOf uses a linear search, just inside a library.

You should write a little library called indexOf that takes two arrays, then you will have code that looks just like indexOf.

But no matter how you do it, it's a linear search under the covers.

edit:

After looking at @ahmadabolkader's answer I kind of take this back.  Although it's still a linear search, it's not as simple as just "implement it" unless you are restricted to fairly small test sets/results.

The problem comes when you want to see if ...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab fits into a string of (x1000000)...aaaaaaaaab  (in other words, strings that tend to match most places in the search string).

My thought was that as soon as you found a first character match you'd just check all subsequent characters one-on-one, but that performance would degrade terrifyingly when most of the characters matched most of the time.  There was a rolling hash method in @a12r's answer that sounded much better if this is a real-world problem and not just an assignment.

I'm just going to vote for @a12r's answer because of those awesome Wikipedia references.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about `String.indexOf(String str)` - it _seems_ like it uses a simple character-by-character linear search (if you examine the java code included with the JDK), but internally the JVM is replacing this with an intrinsic that does something like a poor-man's Boyer-Moore, by creating a bitmap of all the characters present in the string, and trying to examine only every Nth character (where N is the length of the string to find) - if the Nth character isn't in the bitmap, you can skip ahead N characters (since no match is possible that includes that position).

Answer (score 0):

Normally the way you find things in collections in java is

- put them in a hashmap (dictionary) and look them up by their hash.
- loop through each object and test its equality

(1) won't work for you because an array object's hash won't tell you that the contents are the same. You could write some sort of wrapper that would create a hashcode based on the contents (you'd also have to make sure equals returned values consistent with that).

(2) also will require a bit of work because object equality for arrays will only test that the objects are the same. You'd need to wrap the arrays with a test of the contents.

So basically, not unless you write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - there is no faster way to find an array within an array by using some existing construct in Java.  Based on what you described, consider creating a `HashSet` of arrays instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: A HashSet of arrays won't do what you think it does. (Also I don't think that's really the question being asked; I think they mean subarray, not array-containing-arrays-as-elements, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have an array which elements also are array elements? If that is the case and the elements are sorted you might be able to use [binarysearch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) from java.util.Arrays